# angular 5 with jspdf with user inputs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to generate the pdf with the user input. I am using js pdf.

this is my   `Component.ts` file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';

declare var $ :any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    download() {
        let doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
        doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');
        doc.addPage();
        doc.save('Test.pdf');
    }
}
```

`component.html` file

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="test" name="test">
<button (click)="download()">download </button>
```

Comment: What is an actual behavior of this code? Any errors in the console?

Comment: Can you please format your code properly. And what do you mean with "user input"? Do you mean `<input type="file"/>`?

Comment: For example when the user enters his name.

Answer (score 0):

```
**This is my app.component.html**

<input type="text" #test>

<button (click)="downloadPDF()"></button>


**This is my app.component.ts**


import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-add',
  templateUrl: './add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add.component.css']
})
export class AddComponent  {

  @ViewChild('test') test:ElementRef

downloadPDF() {

   let doc = new jsPDF();

   let test =this.test.nativeElement;

  doc.text(80, 20, 'Testing-Page');

    doc.fromHTML(test.value, 70,69);




        doc.addPage();
        doc.text(20, 20, 'Testing-page-2');
 // Save the PDF
        doc.save('Test.pdf');
        }
}
```

Comment: Hmm what is that? Did you want to edit your question and posted a new reply instead?